# How to declare metadata tags using python dominate

Tags: python, refresh, http-equiv, dominate

```
import dominate
from dominate import tags as tags

doc = dominate.document(title="Monitormaneto Data Center EOSP")
with doc:
    tags.meta(<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30; URL="domain.url")
    tags.style("body{font-family:Helvetica}")
    ...
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: so above is not right, because the code does not generate the target TAG, wanted to know how to declare this call with dominate,

Answer (score 0):

Consider revising the argument passed to `tags.meta()` in your code:

```
import dominate
from dominate import tags as tags

doc = dominate.document(title="Monitormaneto Data Center EOSP")
with doc:
    # tags.meta(<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30; URL="domain.url")
    tags.meta(http_equiv="refresh", content="30; URL=domain.url")
    tags.style("body{font-family:Helvetica}")
```

Comment: you should provide more description.